# Inline CSS issues in react component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a `react` component and I'm trying to align the below `div` using `margin-left` property. I'm getting a `console` error:

> Unexpected token

pointing towards the hyphen in the `margin left` property. Can anyone help to resolve this?

```
<div id="loadingDiv" style = {{display:'block'}}>
    <img src={Loading} style = {{width:150,height:150,margin-left:370}} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
style = {{ width : 150, height : 150, marginLeft : 370 }}
```

Instead of using `margin-left` use `marginLeft`.

**Reason**:

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of
>   the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a
>   string.

```
margin-left      -->   marginLeft 
padding-top      -->   paddingTop 
background-color -->   backgroundColor
```

Check the [DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

Comment: what about values?
eg. max-width: 'max-content'
does that become maxWidth: 'max-content'
or maxWidth: 'maxContent' ?

Comment: @Paulo in that case, no change in the property value, only change the name like `maxWidth: 'max-content'`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this as well -

```
const divStyle = {
  display:'block'
};

const imgStyle = {
  width:150,
  height:150,
  marginleft:370
};

<div id="loadingDiv" style= {divStyle}>
    <img src={Loading} style= {imgStyle} />
</div>
```